# what does this python statement mean and what does % mean?

Tags: python, syntax, logic

I am taking a python course and wanted to know what does

```py
arr1=np.array([x for x in range(0,50) if x%5 > 2])
```

mean? Also what is the difference between the given statement and

```py
arr1=np.array([x for x in range(0,50) if x%5 and x> 2])
```

I have also looked on other sites but none seem to answer?

Comment: Are you aware of the `%` modulus operator?

Comment: Did you try? What are the results? What difference do you see beween the results? Do you see a pattern?

Comment: The portion in the square brackets is a list comprehension.  The first one produces a list of numbers in the range 0 through 49, inclusive, if the remainder when divided by 5 is 3 or 4.  The second changes the condition to the remainder being non-zero and greater than 2.

Comment: Which part of this confuses you? Do you e.g. know what this would do? `arr1=np.array([x for x in range(0,50)])`

Comment: @TomKarzes Please use answers for answering, not comments. That way we will have a shorter list of unanswered questions. If you think this should not be answered, then please closevote.

Comment: the modulus function gives you the remainder.I mistook the modulus function for the division function.